# perl - split a logfile

Tags: perl, parsing, split

I have a log file:

```
Wed Oct 17 04:57:08 2018 : Resource = 'test1' cstep= 'titi' time =23.634s 
Wed Oct 17 04:57:50 2018 : Resource = 'test2' cstep= 'titi2' time =22.355s 
Wed Oct 17 04:58:41 2018 : Resource = 'test3' cstep= 'titi3' time =28.611s 
Wed Oct 17 04:58:46 2018 : Resource = 'test4' cstep= 'titi4' time =4.085s
```

I only want lines with more than five seconds:

```
Wed Oct 17 04:57:08 2018 : Resource = 'test1' cstep= 'titi' time =23.634s 
Wed Oct 17 04:57:50 2018 : Resource = 'test2' cstep= 'titi2' time =22.355s 
Wed Oct 17 04:58:41 2018 : Resource = 'test3' cstep= 'titi3' time =28.611s
```

My code is:

```
open (FILE, 'logfile.txt');
while (<FILE>) {

($word1, $word2, $word3, $word4, $word5, $word6, $word7, $word8, $word9, $word10, $word11, $word12, $word13, $word14) = split(" ");
print " $word5-$word2-$word3 $word4 $word5 $word6 $word7 $word8 $word9 $word10 $word11 $word12 $word13 $word14 \n";

}
close (FILE);
exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple notes:

1. Whenever you find yourself writing `$variableN`, you probably want an array
2. The default behavior of [`split`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split) does what you're doing
   3. You need to isolate the field you're interested in, make it numeric, and then do a numeric comparison

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $time = $fields[12];
    $time =~ s/[^\d.]//g; # remove everything except digits and dots

    next unless $time > 5;
    print; # or whatever
}

__DATA__
Wed Oct 17 04:57:08 2018 : Resource = 'test1' cstep= 'titi' time =23.634s
Wed Oct 17 04:57:50 2018 : Resource = 'test2' cstep= 'titi2' time =22.355s
Wed Oct 17 04:58:41 2018 : Resource = 'test3' cstep= 'titi3' time =28.611s
Wed Oct 17 04:58:46 2018 : Resource = 'test4' cstep= 'titi4' time =4.085s
```

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: do you know how to convert Oct month to 10 ?

Comment: @jack94 There are tons of different ways to do that, but the best would be to parse the date and then format it how you want. That’s a separate question, though.

Answer (score 3):

I up-voted the other answers but I have

```
$ perl -ne '/time =(\d+\.\d+)/; if($1>5){print $_;}' file1
Wed Oct 17 04:57:08 2018 : Resource = 'test1' cstep= 'titi' time =23.634s
Wed Oct 17 04:57:50 2018 : Resource = 'test2' cstep= 'titi2' time =22.355s
Wed Oct 17 04:58:41 2018 : Resource = 'test3' cstep= 'titi3' time =28.611s
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the time from $word13 using a regex match and compare it numerically:

```
print " $word5-$word2-$word3 $word4 $word5 $word6 $word7 $word8 $word9 $word10 $word11 $word12 $word13 $word14 \n"
    if $word13 =~ /=([0-9.]+)/ and $1 > 5;
```

Comment: or I had  perl -ne '/time =(\d+\.\d+)/; if ($1>5){print $_;}' file1

Comment: that don't work, do you have a easy code

Comment: @EssexBoy: The OP seems to restructure the line, too.

Comment: @jack94: What doesn't work? I tested my code with your input data and it worked.

Comment: i have the messsage syntax error , near "if $word13"

Comment: @jack94: Did you remove the `;` before the `if`?